# Header Origin vs Host

Tags: header, cross-domain

I have a question about the working of the *Origin* and *Host* HTTP headers.

I have an Ajax page "*Page A*" which will call the Ajax feed "*Page B*".

I saw that the request header of "*Page B*" from the Ajax call contains the headers:

```
Origin: http://example.com
Host: example.com
```

However, if I call the "*Page B*" directly, the request header will only contain the `Host` header:

```
Host: example.com
```

Thus, I want to know what is the difference between the `Origin` and `Host` headers, and why they show up on non-direct calls?

Can *Origin* be prepended and passed to server?

Answer (score 109):

The Host is the domain the request is being sent *to*. This header was introduced so hosting sites could include multiple domains on a single IP.

The Origin header is the domain the request originates *from*.

The Host header is always included. The Origin header is included sometimes: It is always included on cross-origin requests (across all browsers), and in Chrome/Safari, it is also included on same-origin PUT/POST/DELETE requests. Same-origin GET requests do not include an Origin header.

Comment: Thx for the answer, same as above reference link, BTW Can origin be pretended and pass to server

Comment: Origin can't be faked from a browser. A user could use curl in order to craft an HTTP request with an Origin header, but this won't be a typical use case. It is not recommended to use CORS as a security mechanism; if you are trying to secure content, you should also have some auth mechanism such as OAuth2.

Comment: Thx for the answer, im would not use it as security mechanism; ^^

Comment: It's worth mentioning that some browsers (Chrome, Safari, maybe others) do include the Origin header on Ajax POST requests on same domain requests (but not GET requests)

Comment: @user192344, Yes origin can be "faked" from the browser, but it involves an DNS attack to be able to do so (think  DNS poisoning / DNS rebinding). Basically, we corrupt the layer below the browser so it thinks that it is having real values.